# Converting all elements in a 2D array to uppercase in python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array that looks a bit like this:

```
array =[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i', 'k', 'l']]
```

Is there a way of converting all elements of the array into capitals? The only methods I could fine only worked on 1D array or 2D arrays when the sub arrays are the same size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.join()` and `.split()`:

```
array = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i', 'k', 'l']]
# 1. join letters with ' '. 2. UP them. 3. split them with ' '
new_array = [' '.join(a).upper().split() for a in array]
print(new_array) # => [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L']]
```

In case the elements have more then one letter and have spaces between the letters, use this :

```
array = [['a x', 'bq', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'ha', 'd i', 'k', 'l']]

new_array = [[x.upper() for x in a] for a in array]
print(new_array) # => [['A X', 'BQ', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F'], ['G', 'HA', 'D I', 'K', 'L']]
```

Comment: Seriously, what's wrong with people? Taking pride in down-voting? Yes.

Comment: not the cleanest, though it works ! it should not be downvoted

Comment: Glad it helped :).

Answer (score 9):

Could this be what you need, quite simple list comprehension:

```
[[item.upper() for item in sub] for sub in array]
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to use `map` function:

```
>>> map(lambda x: map(lambda y: y.upper(), x), array)
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L']]
```

You can also use list comprehensions:

```
>>> [[x.upper() for x in y] for y in array]
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L']]
```

Comment: This flattens the list though. My interpretation of the OP's question is that the output should have the same shape as the input

Answer (score 0):

```py
for x in array:
    [y.upper() for y in x]
```

Then you have to wrap them into a new array.

A way to do it all together could be:

```py
newarr = []

for x in array:
    newarr.append([y.upper() for y in x])
```

Comment: Of course, this one is made for you to keep the capitalized array, it could be that you don't need it so you can just use the loop

Answer (score 0):

your array should be, elements separated by commas
`array =[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],['e', 'f'],['g', 'h', 'i', 'k', 'l']]`
mapping all elements of all array elemts to upper case
`array_new = list(map(lambda x:list(map(lambda y:str.upper(y),x)),array))`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the result to be the same shape, or one array?

If you want a single array, you could do this:

```
foo = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e"], ["f", "g", "h"]]
[x.upper() for inner in foo for x in inner]
```

If you want the same shape do:

```
[[x.upper() for x in inner] for inner in foo]
```

Note that the ordering is different in the two examples. That's because in the second case Python "loops over" the outer comprehension first, and uses the value over `inner` at each point to evaluate the inner comprehension.

Either way, read up [list comprehensions](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python). They're the best solution for a lot of things in Python.

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Converting to uppercase lists of letters in a list

```
array = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i', 'k', 'l']]

for lists in array:
    for elements in lists:
        lists[lists.index(elements)] = elements.upper()
print(array)
```

> output

[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L']]

## 2. Getting all the elements of the different lists in just one list with a list comprehension

```
array = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i', 'k', 'l']]

array = [lists[lists.index(elements)].upper() for lists in array for elements in lists]

print(array)
```

> output

['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L']

Answer (score 0):

```py
names = np.array([["Izzy", "Monica", "Marvin"],
                  ["Weber", "Patel", "Hernandez"]])
```

Vectorize the .upper() string method

```py
vectorized_upper = np.vectorize(str.upper)
```

Apply vectorized_upper to the names array

```py
uppercase_names = vectorized_upper(names)

print(uppercase_names)
```